# Angularjs: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module

I'm a relative newbie in Angular and after following the tutorial I now want to build something from scratch on my own. So I'm trying to set up a basic app in which I want to use [the $stateProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) (since I read that it is better than the $routeProvider). So this is my html:

```
<html ng-app="formApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `app.js` looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ui-router']);

formApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main')
});
```

But I get a massive error in the console, saying:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module formApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui-router due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ui-router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=ui-router
minErr/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:68:12
etc. etc.
```

I understand that `'ui-router'` in my app declaration is obviously wrong, but without it I get the even bigger error below.

Any idea how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module formApp due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider
minErr/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:68:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:4262:19
getService@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:4409:39
invoke@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:4441:1
runInvokeQueue@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:4356:11
loadModules/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:4365:11
forEach@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:336:11
loadModules@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:4346:5
createInjector@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:4272:11
bootstrap/doBootstrap@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:1630:20
bootstrap@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:1651:1
angularInit@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:1545:5
@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:28359:5
trigger@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:2996:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js:3271:9

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=formApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24stateProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0AminErr%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A68%3A12%0AcreateInjector%2FproviderCache.%24injector%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A4262%3A19%0AgetService%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A4409%3A39%0Ainvoke%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A4441%3A1%0ArunInvokeQueue%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A4356%3A11%0AloadModules%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A4365%3A11%0AforEach%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A336%3A11%0AloadModules%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A4346%3A5%0AcreateInjector%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A4272%3A11%0Abootstrap%2FdoBootstrap%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A1630%3A20%0Abootstrap%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A1651%3A1%0AangularInit%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A1545%3A5%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A28359%3A5%0Atrigger%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A2996%3A7%0AcreateEventHandler%2FeventHandler%40https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3A3271%3A9%0A
```

Comment: may be you are missing to add ui-router js file to project..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to use $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider which are coming from "ui.router", and you didn't inject the dependency "ui.router".

`var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ui.router']);`

That's the error you got, please have a read of https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di .

Comment: does not help .

Comment: @ritesh angular.module('formApp', ['ui.router']); now?

Comment: Thanks exiadbq for the help.

Comment: Not a helpful answer... Please put some code or point to specific location in the existing code. Author has already made changes according to your suggestion, so you need to respond on that as well.

Answer (score 6):

You've got this error because you're injecting `ui-router` instead of `ui.router`

Replace this line in your code :

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ui-router']);
```

With this one :

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ui.router']);
```

And this will work flawlessly

This is a common mistake with this library as its name is **ui-router** but you have to inject **ui.router** instead ;)