# Error: Failed to instantiate module ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have installed angular-ui-router by doing `npm install angular-ui-router --save-dev` but i am getting errors

**Index.html**:

```
 <!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
```

I have added the script tag in index.html and have also injected in app.js

**app.js**

```
angular
.module('news1App', ['ui.router'])
```

But still getting the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs: \[$injector:modulerr\] Failed to instantiate module ui-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693600/angularjs-injectormodulerr-failed-to-instantiate-module-ui-router)

Comment: @serg its not the duplicate, actually OP has injected correctly

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you must be having different version of angular API loaded and bounded together. Ideally you should refer the angular API library with same version.

I'd suggest you to have all angular API version same as 1.5.8. This could solve your problem.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- UI-Router -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://embed.plnkr.co/dPt62QVcsnAI1Djx9jSR/)**